# How to do spatial join between grid and polygons with geotools?

Tags: geotools

I have a GridCoverage2D and and a collection of MultiPoints , so polygons which don't overlap.
Both cover the same geographic area and I want to know in which polygon each point lies. So it's a point-in-polygon problem.

The naive way to do this with geotools, is to iterate over all 700000 points and ask for each 260 times, if it lies in a polygon.
This works, but is terrible slow....

Is there a faster way to do this in geotools ?

Doing something similar in R (using the "over" function), takes acouple of seconds, while my naive nested loop would take hours to run.
As it does 700000 times 100 calls to "within"

```
while(pointFeatures.hasNext())  {
        SimpleFeature pointFeature = pointFeatures.next();
        Geometry   defaultGeometryPoint = (Geometry) pointFeature.getDefaultGeometry();
        PreparedGeometry prep = PreparedGeometryFactory.prepare( defaultGeometryPoint );
        SimpleFeatureIterator polygonFeatures = collection.features();
        while(polygonFeatures.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature polygonFeature = polygonFeatures.next();
            Geometry polygonFeatureDefaultGeometry = (Geometry) polygonFeature.getDefaultGeometry();
            if(prep.within(polygonFeatureDefaultGeometry)) {
                System.out.println("polygonFeature = " + polygonFeature);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this psuedo-code:

```
for each polygon:
    get bounding box
    for x in bbox.minx,bbox.maxx
       for y in bbox.miny,bbox.maxy
           if check ig point(x,y) is in polygon is True
               note point in poly.
```

But it would be much faster if you had actual points not a Grid.